# References on $p$-adic Langlands

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, langlands-conjectures, p-adic-groups

As a student with a background in Algebraic Geometry (up to chapter 3 of Hartshorne) and basic Algebraic Number Theory, where should I begin learning about the $p$-adic Langlands program? What are the fundamental references? Although there might not be a single canonical path through these references, could you recommend a roadmap for me?

Comment: Emerton's ICM article (https://math.uchicago.edu/~emerton/pdffiles/icm.pdf) is a great start. I would also look at Breuil's article from the 2010 ICM. You can also read the introduction of the (rather imposing) Emerton-Gee-Hellmann IHES notes.